# "Alex": Олександр чи Олексій для міжнародного спілкування та аліасів в онлайн сервісах

Tags: власні-назви, non-native-speaker, cross-language-comparison, етикет

Дуже часто при спілкуванні з іноземцями українці спрощують свої імена на латиниці, оскільки для іноземців вимова українських імен часто є надскладним завданням.

Крім того, при реєстрації в онлайн сервісах (месенджерах, соціальних мережах тощо) необхідно вказувати свій аліас, який найчастіше є міксом імені та прізвища латиницею. Зрозуміло, що аліас обирають якомога коротшим задля подальшої зручності у використанні.

Я *Олександр* і завжди користують скороченим аліасом *Alex* (що, очевидно, є коротким варіантом від *Alexandr*). Проте дуже часто в Україні до мене звертаються *Олексій*, вважаючи, що *Alex* - це скорочення *лише* від *Alexey*.

Я схиляюсь до думки, що *Alex* може використовуватись по відношенню як до Олександра, так і до Олексія, проте статистика помилкових звернень свідчить не на мою користь.

Тому питання: **як правильно скорочувати імена *Олександр/Олексій* і чи є якісь правила для такого роду скорочень**?

Comment: Так само скорочую. Думаю обидва варіанти вірні. Наприклад "Славік" це скорочення від "Вячеслав", "Ярослав" і ще деяких "славів". Для україномовних просто варто уточнювати який саме ви "Alex".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Затверджені правила скорочень українських імен мені невідомі. Особливо щодо скорочень латиницею, адже це досить нова тенденція.

Спроби згадати варіації імен на Полтавщині наштовхнули на думку, що українці не схильні до скорочування імен. Навпаки, зменшено-пестливі форми утворюються за допомогою відповідних суфіксів. Скорочення дуже схожі на копіювання російських традицій.

Порівняймо.

*Рос*. Александр - Саша, Алексей - Алеша, Иван - Ваня, Николай - Коля, Григорий - Гриша, Петр - Петя, Екатерина - Катя, Мария - Маша, Ксения - Ксюша, Светлана - Света, Наталия - Наташа, Татьяна - Таня.

*Укр*. Олександр - Олесь, Олексій - Олексійко, Олексієчко, Іван - Іванко, Івасик, Микола - Миколка, Григорій - Григорко, Григоруньо, Петро - Петрик, Петрусь, Катерина - Катруся, Марія - Марійка, Маруся, Оксана - Оксанка, Оксаночка, Світлана - Світланка, Світланочка, Наталія - Наталочка, Тетяна - Тетянка, Тетяночка.

Цю думку підтверджує Леся Храплива-Щур у статті ["СЛОВНИЧОК ДАВНІХ УКРАЇНСЬКИХ ІМЕН"](http://abetka.ukrlife.org/schur_dict.htm) на ресурсі "Весела абетка".

> Українська мова, така багата на форми пестливих здрібнінь, дуже часто
>   має й не одну, а кілька різних здрібнілих назв імен. Деякі такі назви
>   подаємо, а нерідко їх собі видумують самі діти чи їхні не набагато
>   старші брати або сестри. Здрібнілі імена залишаються в родині навіть
>   коли діти виростають. Існує поважна небезпека, що ці здрібніння та
>   скорочення часто не в дусі української мови, а ще трапляються
>   наслідування та кальки із російської мови: Каті, Саші, Віті тощо. Їх
>   треба остерігатися, беручи, зокрема, до уваги, що в українській мові,
>   звичайно, залишається більша частина імені, як в російській (наприклад
>   звук «р» у здрібнінні імені Катерина — Катруся). Чоловічі ж імена не
>   мають у нас здрібніння із жіночим закінченням на — а, — я (Вова, Толя)
>   хіба що в іменах, які самі так закінчуються (Микола, Микита, Сава),
>   але таких імен небагато.

Скорочені ж імена, які пригадуються (Гриць, Стець) мають переважно зневажливий відтінок, за моїми відчуттями. Хоча ті ж Олесь, Михась, Івась вже сприймаються з позитивним забарвленням.

На Полтавщині використовуються скорочені кличні форми (відмінки), але це здебільшого у дуже неформальному (сімейному) спілкуванні (Іване - Іва, Катре - Ка, Михайле - Миха, Миколо - Мико і т.д., з наголосом на останньому складі).

Є **"Словник українських імен"** Івана Трійняка (Словник українських імен / Іван Іванович Трійняк ; Відп. ред. Ірина Михайлівна Желєзняк ; Інститут української мови НАН України . – Київ : Довіра, 2005 . – 509 с.), але я змогла знайти тільки посилання на [Інтернет-магазин](http://artvertep.com/shop/books/null/2380/%3BSlovnik+ukrainskih+imen%3B.html), де його можна придбати.

> "Словник вміщує велику кількість особових імен у їх повній унормованій
>   формі, а також скорочені пестливі, розмовні, зневажливі їх варіанти,
>   найменування жінок за чоловіком, відантропонімні прізвища, що
>   засвідчені на всій території України. В додатках подано географічні,
>   похідні від особових імені прізвищ. Такий набір інформації щодо
>   антропонімікону України вперше відбито в лексикографічній формі."

Ще є робота [Власні імена людей: словник-довідник.](http://books.dokladno.com/text.php?f=Vlasni_imena_liudey_Slovnyk-dovidnyk_2005_OCR&p=0) Скрипник, Л.Г., Дзятківська, Н.П. За посиланням можна завантажити.

Додатково. Знайшла посилання на роботу Павла Чучки ["Слов'янські особові імена українців"](https://books.google.com.ua/books?id=M-sHKtbjF2EC&pg=PA65&lpg=PA65&dq=%D0%A1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA+%D1%83%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%97%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%B8%D1%85+%D1%96%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD+%D0%86%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B0+%D0%A2%D1%80%D1%96%D0%B9%D0%BD%D1%8F%D0%BA%D0%B0&source=bl&ots=1HmoxeVwKb&sig=3Kb4_wFc6aRJZfPyglanrSJBBbk&hl=uk&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi447KbmZnSAhVnCpoKHTpwBKgQ6AEIPDAF#v=onepage&q=%D0%A1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA%20%D1%83%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%97%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%B8%D1%85%20%D1%96%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%20%D0%86%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B0%20%D0%A2%D1%80%D1%96%D0%B9%D0%BD%D1%8F%D0%BA%D0%B0&f=false), історико-етимологічний словник, якщо зацікавить.

Comment: Олександр - Олесь. Оле́сь — українське чоловіче ім'я, за походженням — зменшена форма імені Олександр, що **стала самостійним ім'ям**. Жіночий варіант — Олеся.

Comment: З моїх відчуттів, Гриць і Стець жодної зневажливості не несуть. (Народна пісня може не надто аргумент, але ж «Грицю шапка до лиця, люблю Гриця-молодця»).

Comment: @ata_zh, цитована вами [пісня](http://www.pisni.org.ua/songs/4273889.html) загалом, як на мене, має жартівливо-глузливий "присмак" :)

Comment: Тоді нехай буде дід Гриць [у Стефаника](http://ukrlit.org/stefanyk_vasyl_semenovych/did_hryts) і мій дід Грицько, шанована людина. (Хоча знов недобре, бо це поодиночні випадки, а чи хтось написав дисертацію на тему «емоційне навантаження суфікса -иць», того не знаю).

Comment: @ata_zh, ну то я ж і зауважила - "за моїми відчуттями". Не мала на меті нікого образити, тим паче "шанованої людини - вашого діда Грицька". На підтвердження вашого сприйняття можу ще навести як приклад пісню "Ой, не ходи, Грицю, та й на вечорниці". Тому, знову ж таки, суб'єктивно.

Comment: В жодному разі без образ :) Який приклад маю, такий і наводжу. Можемо зробити висновок, що наші сприйняття рівноцінно мають право на існування )